# Is it possible to do full text search in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

currently, I'm using pandas `DataFrame.filter` to filter the records of the dataset. if I give a word, I have got all the records that are matching with that word. now if I give two words that are present in the dataset but they are not in one record then I got an empty set. Is there any way in either pandas or other python modules that I can find something that can search multiple words ( not in one record )?

With python list comprehension, we can build a full-text search by **mapping**. in pandas `DataFrame.filter` uses indexing. is there any difference between mapping and indexing? if yes what is it and which can give a better performance?

Comment: `.str.contains()` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
     Name  Qty.
0   Apple     3
1  Orange     4
2    Cake     5
```

Considering the above dataframe, if you want to find quantities of Apples and Oranges, you can do it like this:

```
result = df[df['Name'].isin(['Apple','Orange'])]
print (result)
```

Comment: I don't think this would fully match OP's requierements

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomerID  Genre   Age AnnualIncome (k$)   SpendingScore (1-100)
1           Male    19      15                 39
2           Male    21      15                 81
3           Female  20      16                  6
4           Female  23      16                 77
5           Female  31      17                 40
```

```py
pokemon[pokemon['CustomerID'].isin(['200','5'])]
```

Output:

```
CustomerID  Genre   Age AnnualIncome (k$)   SpendingScore (1-100)
5           Female  31     17                      40
200         Male    30     137                     83
```

Comment: your answer is true but its not what i expected.